# Hierarchical Clustering given distance matrix

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

Given a distance matrix

```
d = matrix(c(0,2.5,4.5,2.5,0,3.4,4.5,3.4,0), nrow=3),
```

how to do Hierarchical clustering using R? Using

```
hclust(d)
```

it is given me the error

```
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to an object with `dist`,

```
d1 = as.dist(d)
hclust(d1)
```

---

If you examine `d1`

```
R> str(d1)
Class 'dist'  atomic [1:3] 2.5 4.5 3.4
  ..- attr(*, "Size")= int 3
  ..- attr(*, "call")= language as.dist.default(m = d)
  ..- attr(*, "Diag")= logi FALSE
  ..- attr(*, "Upper")= logi FALSE
```

You can see that R is being clever with what it stores; it only requires the lower triangular matrix.